# Is it possible to rename a release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Can we rename a release in Azure Devops (Not Release Pipeline)?

[image]

I'm not looking to edit the Release name format property in the General page. I want to rename the release once it's already created/forked from the release pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simply answer is, you can't perform a rename operation at a pipeline level. If you want to change it in the Azure portal you can Clone the pipeline from the Author and Deploy blade. Then deploy the pipeline again with the new name and drop the old version.

This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases) also say that if a pipeline is created it creates unique artefacts that can't be renamed. So as mentioned, copy it and make a new one with your new name.

Comment: unfortunately, im looking into renaming the release itself once its forked/created from the release pipeline.

Comment: Okey I understand. It is already released. I updated my answer. Take a look. That's the only possible way til now. Hope your question is answered and your mind more clear. Cheers :)

Comment: oh man i was hoping it can be renamed :( thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not. :( But still you learned somthing. That's most important. :D